# Setting utf-8 charset in http-get attempt

Tags: android

I'm  new in android platform. I use code below to get address from google but i get strange characters. I'm pretty sure that its about setting utf-8 charset into code but i don't know exactly how. I read similar topics that propose :

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
```

But code below works like charm. Any idea how to put charcet utf-8; Sorry for this fundamental question and thanks in advance.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+lng+ "&sensor=true");
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    response = client.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                    int b;
                    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }


                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            try {
                location = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
                location_string = location.getString("formatted_address");
                Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is your problem and what did you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  It would be something like this:

```
         try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8"));

            /*
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
            */

            String line=null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            stream.close();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
```